# dimension of a direct sum is the sum of the separate dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $U$ can be expressed as a direct sum $U=U_1\oplus\dots\oplus U_n$. Then $\dim(U) = \dim(U_1) + \dots + \dim(U_n)$.

---

I don't really have any idea how to prove this, any tips?

Comment: What are you using as the definition of $U_1\oplus U_2$?

Comment: Searching for "dimension of a direct sum" brings up a number of relevant results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* A general theorem states that
$$
\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1\cap U_2)\tag{1}
$$
Can you prove this?

Once we have this general theorem, note that $V=U_1\oplus U_2$ means $V=U_1+U_2$ and $U_1\cap U_2=\{\vec 0\}$. Thus the formula
$$
\dim(U_1\oplus U_2)=\dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)
$$
is a corollary of the formula in (1). Your general formula should then follow from induction.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, $\dim{(U_1\cap U_2)} = 0$, thus $\dim{(U_1+U_2)} = \dim{(U_1)}+\dim{(U_2)}$. Then I understand the induction, thanks.